Create a report from "Yammer" entries
I want to create a report from Yammer entries which should:

report how many likes a question got.
report how many answers the question got.
report maximum likes on any answer for a question.

The report should be executed in a time frame between 1 month and 1 year.
There could be several filters, like the country the user posted or liked, etc..
Is there a possibility to create something like this? Where should I start?
